# Up and Running with Webmatrix

Tags: webmatrix

I have used webmatrix before and it was cool. I downloaded it today and was trying to start a site from Template or Application Gallery and I got the following error. I know Microsoft has stopped active development. There must be a hack around to use it? I tried downloading the installing the extensions they provided too. No Luck! Anyone know how to solve this?

Error:

> Unable to download the Web Platform product list. Check your network
>   connection and try again. If the problem persists, report the issue on
>   the Web Platform Installer forum at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=145244. Details: One or more
>   errors occurred.
>
> 'doctype' is an unexpected token. The expected token is 'DOCTYPE'.
>   Line 1, position 3.
>
> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Xml.XmlException: 'doctype' is an unexpected token. The
>   expected token is 'DOCTYPE'. Line 1, position 3.    at
>   Microsoft.WebMatrix.Gallery.Wizard.GalleryWizardModel.Load()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Xml.XmlException: 'doctype' is an unexpected token. The expected token is 'DOCTYPE'. Line 1, position 3.
>   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Gallery.Wizard.GalleryWizardModel.Load()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---

Comment: looks like support for it ended https://forums.iis.net/t/1238487.aspx?Not+able+to+create+new+web+app+from+template+app+gallery